# causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<DataModel>', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i am new to flutter and i am working Http Post Method. I created a data model for this. The code is below but I get the following warning in the submitData() section: "TThe body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr', is a potentially non-nullable type."

```
Future<DataModel> submitData(String name, String job) async{
    var response = await http.post(Uri.https('reqres.in'),body:{
      "name":name, "job":job});
    var data =response.body;
    print(data);
    if(response.statusCode==201){
      String responseString=response.body;
      dataModelFromJson(responseString);
    }
    else return null; }
```

This is the code of the button I used the submitData I created without any problems as follows.

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async{
              String name=nameController.text;
              String job=jobController.text;

              DataModel data= await submitData(name,job);
              setState(() {
                _dataModel=data;
              });
            },
            child: Text("submit"),
          ),
```

Comment: can you include how you are using `submitData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submitData` method doesn't return nullable dataType, to return null you need to change:

```dart
Future<DataModel?> submitData(String name, String job) async {
```

Also while receiving data, do a null check:

```dart
   DataModel? data= await submitData(name,job);
   if(data !=null){ ....
```

More about [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).